# What is the best way to duplicate InputStream without resorting to byte arrays?

Tags: java

One way to duplicate an InputStream is to convert it into byte array then basically just create two InputStream.

However, suppose the requirement is to have something like this

```
InputStream inputStream = ...;
InputStream copyOfStream = copyOfStream(inputStream);
```

What would be the code for the theoretical `copyOfStream`?

Comment: A stream is just a sequence of data to be read. If you truly want to copy it, you either need a repeatable stream that can be reset (i.e. `markSupported()` returns `true`, then `reset()` the stream back to the beginning), or you need to capture the data from the stream so you can read it again.

Comment: @nickb is correct.  Note that you can create a BufferedInputStream with a specific buffer size, to guarantee you have an InputStream which supports mark() and reset() for that many bytes.

Comment: Exactly, you mark the beginning, read the stream, reset it, read it again.

Answer (score 2):

Consider apache commons class TeeInputStream:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html